# Java String- Font style check

Tags: java, string, clipboard, checkstyle

I need to do `font style check` for my selected text area.

I used `applescript` to copy my highlighted/selected text area to clipboard and retrieve the clipboard value in java. I used `string` to capture the selected/highlighted value.

Is there any way I can do `style check` using `String` in `java`.

Code retrieve clipboard value:

```
    String result = "";
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

    //odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    boolean hasTransferableText = (contents != null) &&
      contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    if ( hasTransferableText ) {
      try {
        result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
      }
      catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex){
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Font Info:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\sa280

\f0\i\fs34 \cf0 testing
\f1\i0  hello\'a0
\b Module 
\b0 \ul world}
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\sa280

\f0\i\fs34 \cf0 testing
\f1\i0  hello\'a0
\b Module 
\b0 \ul world}
```

Please advice. Any advice/references is highly appreciated.

Comment: A little vague here. do you have some code yet?

Comment: @Adel dont have any code for style check since im not very sure how to start it.

Comment: added an edit to my answer below that should give you hand, it was too long to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you are getting are the semantical codes for the rich text format. The code for an entire Java based rtf parser would be to long to post here, but for reference there is a [RTFEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html)0 in Swing and the [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/) project at Apache has a RTFParser.

RTF uses Control Words - they have opening and closing tags similar to other markup languages like:

**EXAMPLE:** \someAsciiTag1 ... \someAsciiTag1

In the case of your question:

Font style is right there in the font table or **\fnttbl** group - groups are encapsulated by braces{}.

Font styles are ordered on an  index like structure with **\f**index**** as the control code.

Next code is **\f**font-family**** and so on.

While global font styles are set at the top of the file in the \fnttbl certain style modifications can be made in the plain text section like html for instance: **\fs20** means font-size = 20 of whatever units are inherited further up the structure like css.

While I could post Java code here to show you how to access a particular tag, *and will if you just need to access a few global elements*, but I don't know the scope of your whole project, if it is your goal to get ALL the style from your text I would really, very strongly encourage you to use one of the parsers available above as RTF is a very complex format.

In case you doubt me on this here is a link to the Microsoft spec it's about 270 pages, the lightest weight implementation that I know of that is pretty close to spec complete is over 9000 lines of code, which is why you probably don't want to do it yourself.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725

**EDIT:**

I realized i didn't fully answer your second question in the previous answer

**\b or \b1 = bold(true or 1)** AND **\b0 = bold(false or 0)**

**\i or \i1 = italic(true or 1)** AND **\i0 = italic(false or 0)**

FYI however, these are not the only ways to set style, rtf allows other less common programatic ways of setting these values. Also there are differences between ascii and unicode rtf codes, so once again use a parser.

I have none the less included the font tag structure so if you want global info you can get it.

```
<fonttbl>   '{' \fonttbl (<fontinfo> | ('{' <fontinfo> '}'))+ '}'
<fontinfo>  <themefont>? \fN <fontfamily> \fcharsetN? \fprq? <panose>? <nontaggedname>?
    <fontemb>? \cpgN? <fontname> <fontaltname>? ';' 
<themefont> \flomajor | \fhimajor | \fdbmajor | \fbimajor | \flominor | \fhiminor |
    \fdbminor | \fbiminor
<fontfamily>    \fnil | \froman | \fswiss | \fmodern | \fscript | \fdecor | \ftech | 
    \fbidi
<panose>    '{\*' \panose <data> '}'
<nontaggedname> '{\*' \fname #PCDATA ';}'
<fontname>  #PCDATA
<fontaltname>   '{\*' \falt #PCDATA '}'
<fontemb>   '{\*' \fontemb <fonttype> <fontfname>? <data>? '}'
<fonttype>  \ftnil | \fttruetype
<fontfname> '{\*' \fontfile \cpgN? #PCDATA '}'
```

That is a list of font data tags and the general structure of the font data in line. Hope that helps.

**EDIT: Follow Up**

Well from look of it you have a nice chunk of Mac rtfd (the extra tags)

> cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360 - tells you it's mac encoded

The first part gives the encoding 
The second gives two main font styles Verdana at f0, and Tahoma at f1
the third line tells you it's white rgb(255,255,255) and all.
the fourth and fifth define tabs and pagination.
the sixth (non-blank) say f0\i\fs34 = Verdana, Italic, size 34 \cf0 is black foreground color
the seventh is Tahoma italic, bold is around module, while world is underlined and so on then repeats.

There is a Java based rtf parser that recently added support for some of the mac custom tags you can find it [on GitHub here](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/com.etranslate.tm.processing.rtf) it should be fairly simple to wire-up the modules and parse any files you may need.

Comment: Thanks J-Boss. I've edited my question and post the **semantical codes** from my testing. As you can see the codes contains `/b` and `/i`. How o fetch this value. do i need to do supstring or there is method to do so. like `isBold` or `isTrue`. Please advice.

Answer (score -1):

You have the formatting data included in your data, only if the text in the clipboard is in Rich Formatted Text (RTF). In this case, when you checked and the content of clipboard contained RTF text, you can check its font and other formatting information. You can use this sample code as a starting point.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class ClipboardTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getClipboardData());
    }

    public static String getClipboardData() {
        String result = "";
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        // odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        DataFlavor dfRTF = new DataFlavor("text/rtf", "Rich Formatted Text");
        DataFlavor dfTxt = DataFlavor.stringFlavor;

        boolean hasTransferableRTFText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfRTF);

        boolean hasTransferableTxtText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfTxt);

        if (hasTransferableRTFText) {
            try {
                result = streamToString((InputStream)contents
                        .getTransferData(dfRTF));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (hasTransferableTxtText) {
            try {
                result = (String)contents
                        .getTransferData(dfTxt);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String streamToString(InputStream transferData) {
        return slurp(transferData, 1024);
    }

    public static String slurp(final InputStream is, final int bufferSize)
    {
      final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
      final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
      try {
        final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        try {
          for (;;) {
            int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (rsz < 0)
              break;
            out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
          }
        }
        finally {
          in.close();
        }
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        /* ... */
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
          /* ... */
      }
      return out.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty in getting font information. Appreciate if you could advice on that. sample code is god's gift for now. :)

Comment: Try this sample code. First copy a RTF text (like a part of Word document) and then run the program. It will print the text including formatting information. Does it work for you?

Comment: I'm getting value like this `{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\adeflang1025
{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset128 Times New Roman;}
{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f2\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset128 Arial;}
{\f3\fnil\fprq2\fcharset128 Arial;}{\f4\fnil\fprq2\fcharset128 MS Mincho;}
{\f5\fnil\fprq2\fcharset128 Tahoma;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue128;}`. How do get the information from this. How to check whether its **BOLD, ITALIC** and so on.

Comment: J-Boss's answer complemented this answer, but come-on, really this answer is a -1?